# Store list of tuples into SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to store a list of tuples `[(2345,'MID'),(4543,'GKP')...]` from my `from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11` dataframe column into my database. I'm trying to insert the table as I create it:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE Match (match_id number, league_id number,\
                               from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11 number')
```

An then:

```
df_match.to_sql('Match', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But this stores the list as binary, and I don't know what column declared type this should be:

```
from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11
b'\x80\xe7K\xb4\x86\x7f\x00\x00@\xe6K\xb4\x86\..
```

I know that theres's this `c.executemany()`, but what is the proper way here?

Comment: What's the dtype of your dataframe column? If it holds tuples, then it's an object ('O') dtype, and this could just be storing/comparing temporary memory addresses. EDIT: you can check the dtype of your column in your console with dataframe_name.column_name.dtype

Comment: yep, `type object`

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQLite, but I would guess your first move (if possible) is to split your column of tuples into two columns of defined types - maybe int64 and unicode? - anyways, whichever matches the type/byte-size of your database.